# MYSQL Query for updating table with IDs of other Table

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL query to insert brand-id and category-id column values in a final table based on the brand,  category and sample tables.

The `brand table`  with two columns

```
->brand id(Int)
->brandname(Varchar)
```

The `category` table have two columns

```
->category id(int)
->categoryname(varchar)
```

The *sample* table have three columns

```
->upc(Bigint)
->brandname(varchar)
->categoryname(varchar)
```

and *final* table have 5 columns

```
 ->upc(Bigint)
 ->brandname(Varchar)
 ->categoryname(Varchar)
 ->brandid(int)
->categoryid(int)
```

please help me to insert the data int a final table.

this is the query I tried help me where I am going wrong.

```
update final f set f.brand_id=(select brand_id from brand b,sample s where b.brandname=s.brandname) where f.upc=sample.upc;
```

Ask me If you need any info rather than being mute, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use update with Join:

```
update final f join (
    select s.upc, b.brand_id
    from brand b join sample s
    on b.brandname=s.brandname
) t on f.upc = t.upc
set f.brand_id = t.brand_id;
```